# Is it possible to write data to hard disk or any memory at 1Gbps ? if not why and how can we achieve that

Tags: hard-drive, usb, memory, disk-space, hardware-acceleration

If I am getting a data at 1Gbps from any sensor or any hardware. how can I write it to memory with same speed ?
I am not bothering about data I want writing speed should match with my receiving speed.

Comment: Looking at e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bit_rates there are plenty of hardware which have bandwidths over 1 Gbps, and unless you need permanent storage with the same write speed it shouldn't even be that hard to achieve sustained speeds over that. But you really should be more specific with what you are asking, as this is rather philosophical and thus not possible to answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. A couple of SSds in RAID will do it [for example](http://www.legitreviews.com/samsung-sm951-m2-pcie-ssds-raid0-performance_161753)

Comment: @renemik thanks for your reply . I want to send data to tx pin of USB port with 500Gbps . will my computer can able to process and stores it

Comment: Given that I don't know your computer or what a tx pin is, I cannot answer that.

Comment: @BhavithCAcharya USB max speed is SuperSpeed USB 10 Gbps (USB 3.1). You will not be able to write 500Gbps.

Comment: I glossed over the fact that you slipped in a 500x increase in the desired transfer rate. Do you want 1 or 500 Gbps?

Comment: @DavidPostill To be precise, only USB 3.1 *Gen 2* provides 10Gbps bandwidth... :P

Answer (score 0):

1Gbps (Gigabit per second) = 1000Mbps (Megabit per second) = 125MB/s (Megabyte per second); Even some modern consumer (spinning) HDD have that kind of sequential R/W speed.

If you are talking about 1GB/s (Gigabyte per second), you probably want an NVMe SSD.